# What is the best way to implement mutually exclusive relationship in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I´m trying to build functional location hierarchy and I started by ***Country*** model/entity. One level down is ***Province*** entity with *ManyToOne* relationship to Country (bidirectional). Now I have ***City*** entity which is *ManyToOne* tied to Province (bidirectional) but this relationship is nullable. But now, if City-Province relationship is empty I need City-Country relationship (nullable as well). So **at least one is required** But if one of those two is already in place, other cannot be entered.

So basically, those two relationships in city (city-province, city-country) are **mutually exclusive** but at least one of them is required. I´m working with **Java** and **JPA (Hibernate)** and I haven´t found any special functionality for implementation of this. Is there any proven or "right" way how to do it?

Comment: There is no such functionality. That's so called "business logic" that you have to implement yourself.

Comment: You could use Bean Validation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't model mutually exclusive associations with JPA or Hibernate. But you can model 2 independent ones and add a BeanValidation constraint. JPA integrates the BeanValidation specification and automatically triggers the validation before persisting or updating and entity.

I explained it in greater details in one of my [Hibernate Tips](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-validate-1-of-2-associations-not-null/). Here's the short form.

You can model 2 associations on your `City` entity.

```
@Entity
@EitherOr
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne
    private Province province;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;

    ...
}
```

Please pay attention to the `@EitherOr` annotation in line 2. This is a custom constraint that I implemented based on the BeanValidation specification. The `@Constraint` annotation specifies the `ConstraintValidator` that will be triggered during the entity lifecycle transition.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {EitherOrValidator.class})
public @interface EitherOr {

    String message() default "A city can only be linked to a country or a province.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

The implementation of the ConstraintValidator is pretty easy. You need to implement the `isValid` method and check that either the `province` or the `country` attribute is not null.

```
public class EitherOrValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EitherOr, City>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(EitherOr arg0) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(City city, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        return (city.getProvince() == null && city.getCountry() != null) 
                || (city.getProvince() != null && city.getCountry() == null);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The least invasive way is to just model `City` accordingly by providing factory methods or constructors that only take one of the two (I usually prefer factory methods as they allow the client to read very nice: `City.in(provice)`):

```
public class City {

  public static City in(Province province) { … }

  public static City in(Country country) { … }

  …
}
```

Internally, you just `null` the other field and keep your JPA mappings, as shown by Thorben. Avoid setters for those fields, and you can never actually create instances of `City` with both values set. If you really do need setters, you want to reject invalid invocations right away, too. This can be unit tested, doesn't need any extra technology like JPA or BeanValidation.